# NSAttributedString with links

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I've an HTML text that I put in a label

```
self.label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:body.toData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
                                                   documentAttributes:nil
                                                                error:nil];
```

the problem is in this HTML there are from 0 to n `<a href>` tag. I have to make this link clickable maybe using `NSLinkAttributeName` but I have no idea how to identify link in the `attributedText` property.

Comment: Use `UITextView` that supports clickable Links or use a custom UILabel, [like this one](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel)

Comment: There are plenty of question to know how to transform a `UILabel` into a clickable link (with only partial parts) with `NSAttributedString`. But since UILabel is not really done for this, I'd recommend also a `UITextView`.